# Add Google Maps dynamically in my application

Tags: c#, google-maps, repeater

I have a application just like justdial.com where whenever an address is entered into a form the address is entered into database from where the same address is used for creating Google Maps.

the entire code is written under repeater tag i.e. every time new address is entered Google map api fetches it and display a map in my application.

Just as done in [justdial.com](http://justdial.com).

The project is done using n-tier C# .NET framework.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" runat="server" onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <h2>Map</h2>
                                    <div style="width:100%; min-height:250px;">
                                    <iframe width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>+India&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>&amp;sll=23.192951,72.6299&amp;sspn=0.024023,0.042014&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>,+Odisha,+India&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=20.344743,85.803818&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>,+Odisha,+India&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>&amp;sll=23.192951,72.6299&amp;sspn=0.024023,0.042014&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>,+Odisha,+India&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=20.344743,85.803818" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
                                    </div>

</ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

for adding a dynamic Google map in my application, I just Deleted the latitude and longitude location from the api code and added my variable at all places where address was entered and it went correct.

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
                                            marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<%#Eval("business_name") %>+<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>+India&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=<%#Eval("business_name") %>+<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=<%#Eval("business_name") %>+<%#Eval("comp_adrs") %>,+Odisha,+India&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed">
 </iframe>
```